# How do I launch Pygubu with Anaconda 3 (Spyder)?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygubu

I am trying to use pygubu designer to make some interfaces. I am using Anaconda and my Python version is 3.7.6. The pygubu-designer.exe file is in the Scripts directory (C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts) but when I want to execute the application, an error code shows up saying the file is not found. Do you have any idea of what is causing this error ? 
I installed pygubu via pip before... Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to execute the application? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I was trying to execute the pygubu-designer.exe file directly by double clicking on it.  I got an error File not found. So i re-installed the pygubu module with the .tar file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With a little thinking I re intalled the pygubu module, and now it's working fine... Sorry for the inconvenience. Have a good day !